# Find m so that f has one local extreme point.

Tags: derivatives

Let $f\colon (-1,1) \to \mathbb R $ and $ f(x)=e^x(x^2+x+m) $.

The function f has only one extreme local point if and only if m belongs to the set:
a) (-5, 1);     b) {-5, 1};     c) [-5, 1);    d) ${\frac{5}{4}}$.

I tried to calcule the derivate and then $\Delta = 0$. I got $m = \frac{5}{4}$, but I'm not sure I set the right condition.

$f'(x)=e^x(x^2+3x+m+1)$

$\Delta=5-4m=0 $

$ m=\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: I think your solution is correct.

Comment: yep, you know that $e^x=0$ has no roots and so you want the quadratic to have exactly 1 root, which means the discriminant is zero ($\Delta=0$), all good :)

Comment: The question asks for values of $ \ m \ $ for which there is only one extremum _within_ the interval $ \ (-1 \ , \ 1) \ $ ; the derivative may have a second zero outside of that interval.  [Note: $ \ m \ $ need not take on _every_ value in the suggested intervals. For $ \ m \ = \ \frac54 \ $ , that function has no extremal points; there is a point of inflection at $  \ x \ = \ -\frac32 \ . $ ]

Answer (score 2):

This problem contains a little "trap" (which I suspect the poser enjoyed placing there).  The function has a domain restriction which is an open interval:  this will mean that absolute extrema are *not* guaranteed, since the Extreme Value Theorem applies to *closed* intervals.  One also needs to be wary that the expression for the function may have relative extrema which are *not* in the domain $ \ (-1 \ , \ 1) \ $ of the function.

So saying, the derivative function has its zeroes (when they exist) at $ \ x \ = \  \ -\frac32 \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{5-4m}}{2} \ \ . $  When the discriminant is zero, the single zero is not in the stated domain, so $ \ m \ = \ \frac54 \ $ will **not** be a correct choice. [In fact, the derivative function is then $ \ f'(x) \ = \ e^x· \left(x + \frac32  \right)^2 \ \ , $ which means that $ \ x \ = \ -\frac32 \ $ is an inflection point for the function curve.]  Setting   $ \ x \ = \ -\frac32 \ + \ \frac{\sqrt{5-4m}}{2} \ \  $ equal to $ \ +1 \ $ or $ \ -1 \ $ will give us bounds of the value of $ \ m \ \ , $ which of course will not be included in the solution interval.  We also see from $ \ x \ = \ -\frac32 \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{5-4m}}{2} \ \  $ that the second extremum (a local maximum) of the function expression remains *outside* of $ \ (-1 \ , \ 1)  \ \ . $